# Why is my vector not printing the String?

Tags: java, string, vector, printf

I'm studying vectors and while practicing with a few exercises i got stuck in this particular one, my code doesn't seem to print the name string, and I don't know why. In the final project I have to print only the name of the students with an average that are >=6, since the names wont print  checked if the code was functional by printing the average of the approved ones instead of the name!
Can you guys help me fix it?

Here's the main class:

```java
package Program;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;
import Entities.Student;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        double grade1;
        double grade2;
        double average;

        System.out.printf("how many students will you enter? ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        Student[] vect = new Student[n]; // vector that will store the students created

        for (int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("imput the name, first and second grade for the student number %d%n ", i + 1);
            name = sc.nextLine(); // reads the name
            sc.nextLine();
            grade1 = sc.nextDouble();
            grade2 = sc.nextDouble();
            average = (grade1 + grade2) / 2;
            vect[i] = new Student(name, grade1, grade2, average);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {

            if (vect[i].getAverage() >= 6.0) {
                System.out.printf("%s%n", vect[i].getName());
                System.out.printf("%.2f%n", vect[i].getAverage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `Student` class:

```java
package Entities;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private double grade1;
    private double grade2;
    private double average;

    public Student(String name, double grade1, double grade2, double average) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade1 = grade1;
        this.grade2 = grade2;
        this.average = average;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getGrade1() {
        return grade1;
    }

    public void setGrade1(double grade1) {
        this.grade1 = grade1;
    }

    public double getGrade2() {
        return grade2;
    }

    public void setGrade2(double grade2) {
        this.grade2 = grade2;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

}
```

The console log and return is as follows:

```
how many students will you enter? 5
imput the name, first and second grade for the student number 1
 John
10.0
9.0
imput the name, first and second grade for the student number 2
 Mary
5.0
4.5
imput the name, first and second grade for the student number 3
 Peter
8.5
9.5
imput the name, first and second grade for the student number 4
 Carl
9.9
7.5
imput the name, first and second grade for the student number 5
 Patricia
2.5
8.0

9.50

9.00

8.70
```

The expected output for the entries in the example were supposed to be:

```
John
9.5

Peter
9.0

Carl
8.70
```

Comment: The infamous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo problem

Comment: It's called "array" in Java, not "vector". `Vector` is an outmoded collection class.

Answer (score 0):

- In case `name` is always **one word, no spaces**, then you can use `scan.next()`.
- In case `name` can have **space**, then you should use `scan.nextLine()` (as you do), and then before getting `scan.nextInt()` you should add `scan.nextLine()` (with skipping the return value).

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class Student {

    private final String name;
    private final double grade1;
    private final double grade2;
    private final double avg;

}
```

```java
public class Program {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final Locale locale = Locale.US;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useLocale(locale);

        System.out.print("How many students will you enter? ");
        int total = scan.nextInt();
        Student[] students = readStudents(total, scan);

        System.out.print("Enter min avg grade: ");
        double minAvg = scan.nextDouble();

        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getAvg() >= minAvg)
                System.out.format(locale, "%s %.1f\n", student.getName(), student.getAvg());
        }
    }

    private static Student[] readStudents(int total, Scanner scan) {
        Student[] students = new Student[total];

        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
            students[i] = readStudent(i + 1, scan);

        return students;
    }

    private static Student readStudent(int num, Scanner scan) {
        System.out.format("Student %d:\n", num);

        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = scan.next();

        System.out.print("1st grade: ");
        double grade1 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("2nd grade: ");
        double grade2 = scan.nextDouble();

        double avg = (grade1 + grade2) / 2;
        return new Student(name, grade1, grade2, avg);
    }

}
```